# jQuery smooth scroll to new page link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Smooth scrolling works fine for same page. But I want smooth scroll to work for other pages when clicked on. For example,
when I click on the services link from the home page, I need to go to that services page and smoothly scroll to that div tag. Can you help me for this.

HTML code

```
        <ul class="secondmenu">
            <li><a href="Home.html#main1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html#main2">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html#templatemo_main">Technology</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html#templatemo_main">Team</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery('.secondmenu a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var target = this.hash;
if (this.href != '#') {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(target).offset().top - 60
    }, 1000);
} });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to go to the corresponding section wen the page loads,you should be writing your script inside the `ready` function.

```
<script>
      $( document ).ready(function(e) {
        var target = window.location.hash; //The hash property sets or returns the anchor part of a URL, including the hash sign
        if (typeof target != "undefined") { //Checks if the variable is undefined incase no hash property exists
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 60
            }, 1000);
           e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps u mate.. :)

Comment: Im not jquey expert, i didn't get your idea :(

Comment: U don't need to be an expert to understand this mate..use this code right after the jquery is loaded

Comment: Ok,i added it, now when i click my homepage links nothing happen.
anything wrong with my above jquery code?

Comment: about.html#main2    is not load. anything need to change?